# unable to recover ftp files

Tags: php, ftp

I have been trying for several days to retrieve the list of folders on my ftp servers, despite the various posts consulted I still cannot resolve an error.

I get this error: **`Warning: ftp_nlist() expects parameter 1 to be resource, bool given in D:\Web\www\Design\index.php on line 10`**

My code:

```
<?php
$serveur = '***';
$login = '***';
$pass = '***';

$ftp = ftp_connect($serveur, 21) or die('error connect');
$ftp_login = ftp_login($ftp,$login, $pass) or die('error login');

ftp_nlist($ftp_login, '.');
?>
```

Has anyone already encountered this problem?

The connection to the server is done well, $ftp & $ftp_login returns true

Thanks!

Comment: [ftp_login()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-login.php) return a Boolean, not the connection. The connection is stored in `$ftp`. Try `print_r(ftp_nlist($ftp, '.'));` and see what you get.

Comment: I tried, this time the error disappears, I have a blank page

Comment: That means that `ftp_nlist()` didn't return anything, or an error occurred. Check the PHP error log, or [switch on error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display).

Comment: The error log gives me this error: 
`[19-Mar-2023 09:58:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  ftp_nlist(): Une tentative de connexion a échoué car le parti connecté n’a pas répondu convenablement au-delà d’une certaine durée ou une connexion établie a échoué car l’hôte de connexion n’a pas répondu.
 in D:\Web\www\Design\index.php on line 14
[19-Mar-2023 09:58:55 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[19-Mar-2023 09:58:55 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() D:\Web\www\Design\index.php:0
[19-Mar-2023 09:58:55 UTC] PHP   2. ftp_nlist($ftp = resource(2) of type (FTP Buffer), $directory = '.') D:\Web\www\Design\index.php:14`

Comment: Ah, that sounds like the FTP server is not responding as expected. Have you tested the server with a normal FTP client, like [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/), _with the same settings_, no SSL, and can you connect and retrieve a directory?

Comment: This is the first thing I did to be sure of the identifiers, I just did it again to be sure, I have access to my ftp server, instant connection (https://prnt.sc/hEF8uw8Q-QxV)

Comment: It says it is using a TLS connection, so you're not using the same settings.

Comment: Thank you for the information I had not paid attention to these details, not having my computer because of business trip I would make the changes when I return in a few days.  Thanks again for helping me solve this problem 

Comment: hey,
Sorry for the late reply,
I therefore tried to connect to the servers in secure mode but also in non-secure, the 2 connections work without worries. I really don't see where the problem could come from.

I will try to contact my host in parallel in case he blocks external connections, you never know.

Comment: EDIT: Out of curiosity I created a local ftp server with filezilla server, I used the identifiers created and this time I manage to read all the files available

Answer (score 0):

The ftp_login function returns true if the logi is succesful, false otherwise.
You need to pass the ftp instance as the first param of the `ftp_nlist` function.
Currently, you are passing a boolean value.

Your code should be like the following:

```
<?php
$serveur = '***';
$login = '***';
$pass = '***';

$ftp = ftp_connect($serveur, 21) or die('error connect');
$ftp_login = ftp_login($ftp,$login, $pass) or die('error login');

if(!$ftp_login){
  //login failed
  echo "login failed";
  exit;
}

$files = ftp_nlist($ftp, '.');

var_dump($files);
exit;
?>
```

In the above code i added a check to know if the logi is successfull by checking the value present in the `$ftp_login` variable, if true, the logi is of, otherwise the login has failed.

Comment: The connection returns no error, however the page loops without loading anything until you get the following message: bool(false)

See here: https://icekom.fr/small.php